# AuthorizeForScopes could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnet) tutorial to get access token for my ASP.NET MVC web application built on .NET Framework 4.8.

This is my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
    {
          // Get an authorization header.
          IAuthorizationHeaderProvider authorizationHeaderProvider = this.GetAuthorizationHeaderProvider();
          string[] scopes = new string[]{"user.read"};
          string authorizationHeader = await                  authorizationHeaderProvider.CreateAuthorizationHeaderForUserAsync(scopes);
 
          // Use the access token to call a protected web API.
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
          string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> The type or namespace name 'AuthorizeForScopes' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I couldn't find any discussion on this issue. Why I am getting this error? What is the solution?

Comment: Did you add the [Microsoft.Identity.Web v2.13.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.authorizeforscopesattribute?view=msal-model-dotnet-latest) package to your project?

Comment: @Jackdaw Yes, Microsoft.Identity.Web v2.13.4 is installed. When use it, I got warning saying "using directive is unnecessary".

Comment: The post you are referencing [A web app that calls web APIs: Acquire a token for the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnet) is related to the ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core. It even will not compiled in the ASP.NET Framework MVC.

Comment: For example, the `IActionResult` interface can't be used as a result object in the ASP.NET Framework MVC. To understand what authorization packages can be used for different frameworks see [Microsoft libraries supporting web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#microsoft-libraries-supporting-web-apps)